# Can I sum over the power set of the natural numbers?

Tags: measure-theory, summation, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am aware of three types of summations:

---

The discrete sum can be used on a finite or countably infinite set, such as the naturals.

$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{2^n}
$$

---

The integral sum can be used on an uncountable set provide that such set are continuous. For example on the reals:

$$
\int_a^b x dx
$$

---

Finally, I am aware of the functional integral which sums over an uncountable space of functionals:

$$
I=\iint D\gamma \exp \left(\int_a^b Ldt \right)
$$

---

However, in the case of the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$, I obtain uncountably infinitely may set of natural numbers (including infinite sets). What type of sums, notations and what is the concept behind summing over such a set? I do not see how any of these three sums are applicable. For instance, the set of sets does not appear to work well with integrals. How can I then do this?

Specifically, I have a function $F:\mathcal{P}[\mathbb{N}] \to [0,1]$ and I would like to sum it over all elements of the power set of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$? You can think of it as normalization. I assume can't use integrals, because I can't define an infinitesimal of $\mathcal{P}[\mathbb{D}]$.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call integration a "sum". It has many sum-like properties, but changing one "addend" value has no effect on the "sum".

Answer (score 2):

You want
$$  \sum_{x \in \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})} F(x)  $$

In real analysis, the sum of a set of nonnegative summands is defined to be the [supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) of the collection of sums of finitely many summands.  (Since the summands are nonnegative, we may rearrange them at will and get the same result.  Contrast with the [Riemann Rearrangement Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).)

Note that if $F$ takes values greater than any particular positive value infinitely many times, the finite sets that include more and more of these lower bounded summands will force the supremum to infinity.  So to have a finite sum, the number of $F$ values greater than any particular lower bound must be finite.  Then, much as the terms of a (usual) series must go to zero, the infimum of the summands of this sum must be zero.  (The easiest way for this to happen is for only finitely many summands to be nonzero.)

Comment: The output of the function is a real number between 0 and 1, not either 0 or 1 as discrete values (sorry if I used the wrong notation). I am not sure if this changes your answer?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay : Small text on a phone -- misread the brackets.  It sort of changes the answer.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay : Fixed, I think.

Comment: I do believe your answer is correct, but my initial intuition is a bit different and I am grateful if you could help me clear this up. I understand that the power set of the natural is isomorphic to the reals. Furthermore, on the reals, I can use the integral. So, what is different between the reals and the power set of the naturals that I can use the integral on one, but not the other --- if the two are isomorphic?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay : When one studies real analysis, the difference between a sum and an integral vanishes -- a sum is an integral where the [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) in the differential element of the integral is concentrated only on the the values that the sum's index takes.  One realizes that sums and integrals are both sums over uncountable sets -- for the sum, almost all the summands are $0$.  See the Discussion at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure for more on sums over the measure given by your $F$ over $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$.